# Loop over different combinations of variables in R

Tags: r

I have 8 variables; 1 till 8, and I want to loop over all combinations of the variables and write them to a table. But I want no doubles like: (1,2 == 2,1). This are several options as example.

```
              variables
   Option 1:   1, 2            
   Option 2:   1, 3
   Option 3:   1, 4 
   .....
   Option 8:   1, 8 
   Option 9:   1, 2, 3
   Option 11:  1, 2, 4
   .......
   option 15:  1, 2, 8
```

My goal is to write this to a table as followed (I think this is the easiest order with writing a loop)

```
 Var1     Var2     Var3     Var4     Var5     Var6     Var7     Var8
 1        2 
 1        3  
 1        4
 ..........
 1        8
 1        2        3
 ...................etc.
 1        2        8
 ...................etc.
 1        2        3       4        5        6        7        8
 2        3
 2        4
 ..........etc.
 2        8
```

I was able to create the first part, this is the code:

```
df <- data.frame(matrix(vector(), 0, 8))
x = 1

for (i in 1:1){
  for(j in 1:8){
    if(i == j){
    } else{
      df[x,1] <- 1
      df[x,2] <- j
      x = x + 1
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`combn` will give you different number of possible combinations of variables, e.g.

```
combn(c("A", "B", "C"), 2)

#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,] "A"  "A"  "B" 
# [2,] "B"  "C"  "C"
```

Each column represent a set of combinations, i.e. c("A", "B"), c("A", "C"), c("B", "C").

Using `combn` and `plyr::ldply` on 1 to 8 combinations of 8 variables:

```
var <- letters[1:8]
all <- ldply(1:8, function(x)t(combn(var, x)))
all[seq(1,nrow(all), 40),]

#     1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8
# 1   a <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
# 41  a    b    g <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
# 81  c    f    h <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
# 121 a    d    f    g <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
# 161 d    f    g    h <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
# 201 b    c    d    f    g <NA> <NA> <NA>
# 241 b    c    d    e    f    h <NA> <NA>
```

Comment: perfect, I could also do it with: var <-  c(1:8)

Answer (score 3):

```
x <- list()
for(i in 2:8) {
x[[i]] <- combn(8,i)}
```

This should generate the desired combinations in a list of matrices format and you can manipulate it in the way you wish.